# Magento display subcategories name on product page

Tags: php, magento

I am looking at displaying the names of the sub-categories that have been selected within the admin area of Magento on the single product page.

I have the template open, but I just need to call the relevant code, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$onCatalog = false;
if(Mage::registry('current_product')) {
    $onCatalog = true;
}
```

Comment: Nope, no luck with that I am afraid! I would be needing to define which category sub category it will be! Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming you are inside the product view template, view.phtml):

```
<?php foreach($_product->getCategoryCollection() as $_cat): ?>
    <?php echo $_cat->getName() ?><br />
<?php endofreach ?>
```

That should get you started and get a list of the categories the product has been assigned to.

If you would rather thave the IDs:

```
<?php $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds() // an array ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this.

```
<h2>This product is in the following categories</h2>
                <ul>
                  <?php 
                    $categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection();
                    $categories->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'url'));
                    foreach ($categories as $category){
                      if ($category->getName() == 'Default Category' || $category->getName() == 'Categories') {
                        continue;
                      }
                  ?>
                  <li><a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a></li>
                  <?php } ?>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, if your're in catalog>product>view.phtml or catalog>product>list.phtml

```
<?php foreach($_product->getCategoryCollection() as $_cat): ?>
    <?php echo $_cat->getName() ?><br />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Otherwise, first line should get your the product:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

Would give your currently selected product.

While:

```
$_product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->load(35)
```

Would get you product 35.